# Perl: How to print next line after matching a pattern?

Tags: perl, pattern-matching

I would like to print specific data after matching a pattern or line. I have a file like this:

```
#******************************    
List : car  
Design: S  
Date: Sun 10:10  
#******************************

b-black  
g-green
r-red  

Car Type              No.           color  
#-------------------------------------------    
N17              bg099            g  
#-------------------------------------------    
Total 1 car  

#****************************** 
List : car  
Design: L  
Date: Sun 10:20  
#******************************

b-black  
g-green
r-red  

Car Type            No.            color   
#-------------------------------------------    
A57            ft2233            b  
#-------------------------------------------    
Total 1 car  

#******************************    
List : car  
Design: M  
Date: Sun 12:10  
#******************************    

b-black  
g-green
r-red  

Car Type           No.             color  
#-------------------------------------------    
L45            nh669             g   
#-------------------------------------------    
Total 1 car  

#. .    
#. .     
#.    
#.
```

I want to print the data for example after the lines "Type...." and dashes line"------" which is N17 and bg099. I have tried this but it cannot work.

```
my @array;    

While (@array = <FILE>) {    

foreach my $line (@array) {    

if ($line =~ m/(Car)((.*))/) {      

my $a = $array[$i+2];    
push (@array, $a);    
}  

if ($array[$i+2] =~ m/(.*)\s+(.*)\s+(.*)/) {    
my $car_type = "$1";      
print "$car_type\n";      
}      
}    
}
```

Expected Output:

```
Car Type            No.  
   N17             bg099  
   A57             ft2233    
   L45             nh669  
   ..              ..  
   .               .
```

Comment: Your question does match with your description.You say print next two lines.and inside the question has to print only one line after matching two lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
while (<FILE>) { #read line by line
    if ($_ =~ /^Car/) { #if the line starts with 'Car'
        <FILE> or die "Bad car file format"; #read the first line after a Car line, which is '---', in order to get to the next line
        my $model = <FILE>; #assign the second line after Car to $model, this is the line we're interested in.

        $model =~ /^([^\s]+)\s+([^\s]+)/; #no need for if, assuming correct file format #capture the first two words. You can replace [^\s] with \w, but I prefer the first option.
        print "$1 $2\n";
    }
}
```

Or if you prefer a more compact solution:

```
while (<FILE>) { 
    if ($_ =~ /^Car/) { 
        <FILE> or die "Bad car file format"; 
        print join(" ",(<FILE> =~ /(\w+)\s+(\w+)/))."\n";
    } 
}
```

Comment: I had almost exactly the same answer half-written.

Comment: @Mattan - I applied your coding but I get different result. It only prints,  7 9 , 7 3, 5 9. Do you mind to explain your coding? Thanks and appreciate.

Comment: I fixed the code (put the plus in the second regex inside the capturing expression instead of the outside of it). I also added comments.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another option:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Car Type\tNo.\n";

while (<>) {
    if (/#-{32}/) {
        print "$1\t$2\n" if <> =~ /(\S+)\s+(\S+)/;
        <>;
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Car Type    No.
N17 bg099
A57 ft2233
L45 nh669
```

Usage: `perl script.pl inFile [>outFile]`

Edit: Simplified

Answer (score 2):

I got your code to work with a couple small tweaks.
It's still not perfect but it works.

- "while" should be lower case.
- You never increment $i.
- The way you reuse @array is confusing at best, but if you just output $a you'll get your car data.

Code:

```
$file_to_get = "input_file.txt";
open (FILE, $file_to_get) or die $!;

my @array;

while (@array = <FILE>) {
    $i = 0;

    foreach my $line (@array) {

        if ($line =~ m/(Car)((.*))/) {
            my $a = $array[$i+2];
            push (@array, $a);
            print $a;
        }

        $i++;
    }
}
close(FILE);
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
while (my $line = <>) {
    next unless $line =~ /Car\s+Type/;
    next unless $line = <> and $line =~ /^#----/;
    next unless $line = <>;
    my @fields = split ' ', $line;
    print "@fields[0,1]\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'if(/Type/){$a=<>;$a=<>;$a=~m/^([^\s]*)\s*([^\s]*)\s/g; print $1." ".$2}' your_file
```

tested:

```
> perl -lne 'if(/Type/){$a=<>;$a=<>;$a=~m/^([^\s]*)\s*([^\s]*)\s/g; print $1." ".$2}' temp
N17 bg099
A57 ft2233
L45 nh669
```

if you want to use awk,you can do this as below:

```
> awk '/Type/{getline;if($0~/^#---*/){getline;print $1,$2}}' your_file
N17 bg099
A57 ft2233
L45 nh669
```

Answer (score 1):

a **shell** one-liner to do the same thing

```bsh
echo "Car Type            No.  "; \
    grep -A 2 Type data.txt \
    | grep -v -E '(Type|-)' \
    | grep -o -E '(\w+ *\w+)'
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution using Perl flip-flop operator. Assumption from the input that you always have Total line at the end of the block of interest

```
perl -ne '$a=/^#--/;$b=/^Total/;print if(($a .. $b) && !$a && !$b);' file
```