# search for string in file and extract next line

Tags: perl

I'm trying to search for a string in file. The string can occur multiple times in the file. If found, I need to extract the lines below it within the `<P>` and `</P>` tags.

So far I have the below code:
Only the current lines are printed. How can I get this to print the nextline within the      `<P>`and `</P>` tags?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
my $find = "Primary objectives";

open(FILE,"obj_doc.html") or die "cannot open file ";
my @line = <FILE>;
for (@line) {
    if ($_ =~/$find/) {
        print "Current line is: $_\n";
        # get the next line
        # if next line begins with <P> and ends with </P> extract it. else ignore it
        my $nextline = <FILE>;
        printf "$nextline";

        if ($nextline =~ /^<P>:+<\/P>$/) {
            print $nextline;
        }
    }
}


close(FILE);
```

Thanks much in advance.
- Simak

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? There are several [HTML parsers for Perl](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Parser/Parser.pm) which makes this easy.

Comment: I agree with @m0skit0, use a parser.  FWIW your skeletal program as it is shown has a fundamental flaw that you have read the whole file into ``@line`` then in a loop of ``@line`` you try to read the file further with ``my $nextline = <FILE>;`` But of course the filehandle at that point has nothing more to give!!

Comment: Thanks - yes, I am aware of the parsers. But the problem with using it is that the tags generated are not consistent across all the files I need to process. For example: In File 1, primary objectives is in a paragraph and in file 3, it is a header. Also, there are no other identifiers in the file which I can specify to extract them. So, this roundabout search and extract.

Comment: have a check on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15331762/perl-how-to-print-next-line-after-matching-a-pattern

Comment: what does colon in `/^<P>:+<\/P>$/` mean?

Comment: the colon is a typo actually. it does not exist after the <P>tag in the file

Answer (score 0):

Flip-flop operator is your friend for dirty job.

```
perl -ne'print if/<P>/../<\/P>/'
```

Anyway use proper parser for serious work!