# perl search and replace with new lines

Tags: perl

I need to be able to run a perl script that searches and replaces the 3 lines under [ RemotePhoneBook0 ]

so here is an excerpt from file:

```
[ RemotePhoneBook0 ]
path = /config/Setting/Setting.cfg
URL =
Name =

[ RemotePhoneBook1 ]
path = /config/Setting/Setting.cfg
URL =
Name =
```

I can not touch [RemotePhoneBook1]. When I am done this same excerpt above should look like:

```
[ RemotePhoneBook0 ]
path = /somePath/to/someDir
URL = someUrl
Name = someName

[ RemotePhoneBook1 ]
path = /config/Setting/Setting.cfg
URL =
Name =



s/^<<<what can i put here>>>\s*=.*/somePath/;
s/^<<<what can i put here>>>\s*=.*/someUrl/;
s/^<<<what can i put here>>>\s*=.*/someName/;
```

Comment: You do something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15332095/4883117), matching `RemotePhoneBook0` and then reading and editing the next three lines.

Comment: It looks like a ini file. Take a look at https://metacpan.org/pod/Config%3a%3aIniFiles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity this is what i did:

```
    open my $in,"<","$directory/$files";
    open my $out,">","$directory/temp.txt";

    my @lines = <$in>;
    close $in;
    #print "@lines";
    for($index=0;$index<=$#lines;$index++){
            my $this = $lines[$index];
            if ($this eq "[ RemotePhoneBook0 ]\n"){
                    $lines[$index] = "[ RemotePhoneBook0 ]\n";
                    $lines[$index+1] = "path=\n";
                    $lines[$index+2] = "URL = http:\/\/someUrl\n";
                    $lines[$index+3] = "Name = Users\n";
                    $lines[$index+4] = "\n";
                    $index++;
                    $index++;
                    $index++;
                    $index++;
                    }else{
                            $lines[$index] = $this,"\n";
                    }
    }
    print $out @lines;
```

this prints each line while replacing the lines i care about.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `Config::IniFiles` for such a task:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use Config::IniFiles;

my $ini = Config::IniFiles->new( -file => "stackoverflow_30472923.ini" );

# print $ini->val("RemotePhoneBook0", "path");

$ini -> setval('RemotePhoneBook0', 'path', '/somePath/to/someDir');
$ini -> setval('RemotePhoneBook0', 'URL' , 'someUrl'             );
$ini -> setval('RemotePhoneBook0', 'Name', 'someName'            );

$ini -> WriteConfig("stackoverflow_30472923.modified.ini");
```

Comment: admins of server I am working on wont allow me to add any modules, and this server lacks IniFiles.....